# How to control a popup window in dart

Tags: dart

I wonder if it is possible in dart to open a popup window and then control it from the opener context.

What I would like is to open a popup window, and then control it's content and event from the script that opened it.

The propblem is that window.open only returns a WindowBase, that can only close the popup, nothing more.

So, is it doable ?

Comment: Have you considered using a bootjack modal instead?

Answer (score 1):

I can't test right now but this should work:

```dart
var w = window.open(...);
w.document.body.innerHtml = 'from parent';
```

This of course won't work if the opened site is not in the same origin.

If it's a site you control, you could pass in a parameter in the URL that you can then read and act on.

Comment: Doesn't work: "Breaking on exception: Class '_DOMWindowCrossFrame' has no instance getter 'document'." And I need to control it over time, passing argument to the popup is not enough...

Comment: Perhaps you could use Cross-document Messaging? http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Window.html#postMessage

Comment: That would mean that I would need to load code into the popup first. I wanted to load an empty popup and then populates it from the opener.

Comment: What's the URI you are using? Is the target domain different from the parent domain?

Answer (score -1):

A div with a high z-index and the right positioning and styling could function as a popup window easy to manipulate.